# How to get the size of the duplicates in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following data:

```
md5          file_size          
1234          127.4
1234          127.4
1234          127.4
909           18.2
909           18.2
104           207
```

I want to find out how much data I have in duplicates -- that is -- if we have one of each of the files (unique by md5) how much space do we save? The answer should be:

```
md5        size_saved
1234       254.8
909        18.2
104        0
```

Here is the base query I have thus far:

```
SELECT file_size, SUM(file_size) total_size FROM files GROUP BY md5
```

I think the simplest way to do this is to do `ABS(file_size - total_size)`, but I'm not sure how to do this without using a sub-select or an outer-query that has access to both the aggregate size and the single file size. What would be the proper way to do this, or is the only way with a subselect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT
    md5,
    SUM(file_size) - MIN(file_size) AS size_saved
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    md5;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that my answer assumes that all records for a given `md5` would always have the same `file_size` values, in the event that there be more than one record.  If not, then my answer would not work, but we would have to redefine the logic anyway in this case.

Comment: thanks for this, yes I think I was getting confused in my previous queries as there is some null data in there so the records kept looking wrong. Anyways, yes this is the right answer cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I supposed if it is duplicate, the file size is the same, so you can try something like this :

```
select md5,file_size*(count(file_size)-1) as space_saved from files group by md5,file_size
```

Comment: looks good. Why the group by on the `file_size` though? Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: @David542, without file_size in GROUP BY the SQL would be invalid. MySQL (at least older versions) allows it unless ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is used. Allowing partial group by can lead to non-deterministic results.

Comment: @viorel -- that's my favorite part about older mysql versions! I find it so annoying when every field needs to be grouped or added in with an aggregated calc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `file_size` in GROUP BY, so you can easily include in select statement.

```
SELECT md5, SUM(file_size) -  file_size AS size_saved
FROM files
GROUP BY md5, file_size
```